# React Hooks / Redux and onChange event

Tags: reactjs, redux, onchange

I have the following problem:

I am using react redux with react hooks and also redux-persist.

If I open my react app, available filters will be loaded (using an object).

As I use some input fields that have onChange events and these onChange events trigger a filtering, the filtering does not work as the filter values are not existing at that point.

For instance:

```js
onChange = {
  e => {
    item.dispatchFn(e);
  }
}
```

And the dispatchFn is:

```js
dispatch(Action.setEmployment(data));
```

So the problem is: the onChange event is fired before the component has been rendered and the filter have been loaded.

How can I solve the issue ? What is a usual way to get a solution for that ?

Comment: Can you post your code? About the onChange function.

Comment: @jdn yes did that.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply put wrap your onChange function's work with a if statement (with something like this.state.loaded), then you can use the componentDidMount hook to change the state and allow the onChange event to do it's usual work. For example:

```
componentDidMount() {

this.setState({
loaded: true
});
}

onChange = e => {
if(this.state.loaded){
/* do your onChange job
}
}
```

For functional components:

remember to import setState from React:

```
import { setState } from 'react'
```

Then you set the state and use the useEffect to process code after the render (dont forget to set the state)

```
const [state, setState] = useState({loaded: false});
useEffect(() => {
if(!state.loaded) setState({ loaded: true 
  });
});
```

Update your onChange function:

```
onChange = {
  e => {
if(state.loaded){
    item.dispatchFn(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using React Hooks, I do not have a componentDidMount() and also no setState.

Comment: made an edit using hooks for functional components, check out